# cannot connect to DHCP server

Tags: networking, dhcp, wired-networking

I have the following network setup:

A **fiberoptic router** (provided by service provider, no wireless functionality) -> to a **wireless Linksys router** (to get wireless coverage at home) -> to **Switch 1** -> to 
**Switch 2** (in another room, cabling is through a wall) -> output to computers.

ISSUE: When I connect a computer to any output of *Switch 2*, it gets an IP Address of `169.254...`, which tells me that it cannot negotiate with the DHCP server (in the Linksys router), whereas if I connect a computer to the cable that goes from *Switch 1* to *Switch 2*, it works fine. I'm not able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Switch 2 is nothing more than a simple switch?  Make and model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one looks obvious:

The cabling between switch one and switch two is faulty or switch two has taken a complete crap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific.  If switch 1 and 2 are unmanaged, then the answer Scandalist gave is probably correct.  If they are managed, then you might be looking at incorrect configuration. Try swapping the switches and see if anything that connects to switch 2 (now hooked directly to Linksys) works.  If that works, try switch 1.